# Are these skills not part of any skill group?

Tags: skills, shadowrun-sr5

I am reading over the Shadowrun 5e core rulebook and see *a lot* of skills that are not included in any skill group (even when obviously you can group them and I would even expect it in this type of game):

- Escape Artist (AGI)
- Locksmith (AGI)
- Perception (INT)
- Demolitions (LOG)
- Arcane (LOG)
- Chemistry (LOG)
- Forgery (LOG)
- Enchanting (MAG)
- Assensing (MAG)

Are these skills really not part of any skill group?

Comment: What kind of information or source are you looking for? You have already read the part of the book listing the skill groups. You think there is more information hidden somewhere?

Comment: @Szega, yes. I am looking for the opinion of experienced players.

Comment: @Szega I think that confirming one's understanding of the rules is valid, although casual readers (like me) would benefit from the question explaining what effect these skills *not* being in a skill group has on the game broadly. (J. Doe, the site prefers problems that've been experienced or could be experienced during play. If this question is *just* posed out of curiosity, that's cool, but the question may not get the attention you want if no problem is solved by answering it.)

Comment: Point of Note:
Enchanting is not a skill. It is the name for the skill group containing Alchemy, Artificing, and Disenchanting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### There are skills without a group

The list of skill groups (and the skills included within them), as can be found on page 90 of the Core Rulebook (and is also repeated in other places) is **exhaustive**. There are no other skill groups.

Also, if you look at the descriptions of individual skills (starting on page 130), the ones you list clearly say: "Skill Group: No", further reinforcing that this is not an oversight.

Note: There are other skills without a group, like Archery.